# App is Crashing When Turning on Flashlight when using ocr

Tags: xamarin.android

Problem when using the flash light while reading in the OCR libraries The flash stops and there is no way to turn it on

Comment: The camera flash and flashlight of your device may use the same flash component. OCR will use the camera function. When opening the camera, the flashlight will be closed automatically if it has been opened.The two functions couldn't be used at the same. You could vertify that on a physical device.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way to use both together?

Comment: Yes, Android camera and flashlight are mutually exclusive, we cannot make the camera to do two different work at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the response and follow-up

Comment: It's my pleasure.